# Why Alarm Manager only updates in 30 minutes?

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I wanted to make a widget that updates every sec(more battery consumption) or min(less battery consumption).

I followed as in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15751682/1009225)

, but runs only in every 30mins.

I configured that, once onUpdate is run, it updates in 1mins and
onReceived is run in every 30mins.

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You are not showing any code, so besides the missing code we do not know what you did wrong...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are doing nothing wrong, the widget service indeed only updates every 30 minutes(minimum).

To make it update faster you need to use [AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example), or your own application that will call the service. Unlike soulreaver answer, the alarm manager does work with times less then 1 minute.

Comment: I this this is working:

am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), 1000 * 60 * 10, pi); // Millisec * Second * Minute

changed the code and its working.

Comment: @soulreaver read your own answer: "Applications whose targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when requested.", if I target below version 19 I will not be effected. Also I am not sure if it's matter in this case.

Comment: Neither me, I don't know which APIs you target. I'm only saying it won't work on devices witch KITKAT installed. I would never release app which is uncompatible with newer devices in the moment it is released.

Answer (score 2):

From my experience `AlarmManager` doesn't work well (or at all) with intervals lower than 1 minute. Besides:

> Note: The Alarm Manager is intended for cases where you want to have
>   your application code run at a specific time, even if your application
>   is not currently running. For normal timing operations (ticks,
>   timeouts, etc) it is easier and much more efficient to use Handler.

Moreover:

> Note: Beginning with API 19 (KITKAT) alarm delivery is inexact: the OS
>   will shift alarms in order to minimize wakeups and battery use. There
>   are new APIs to support applications which need strict delivery
>   guarantees; see setWindow(int, long, long, PendingIntent) and
>   setExact(int, long, PendingIntent). Applications whose
>   targetSdkVersion is earlier than API 19 will continue to see the
>   previous behavior in which all alarms are delivered exactly when
>   requested.