# Killing service kills repeating alarm

Tags: android, service, alarmmanager

In my Android app, I use a repeating alarm from AlarmManager to start my service. Everything works fine. However, if I go to system setting, I notice my app running even when the service has completed its stuff and has stopped itself. Not sure why the system shows it still running. If I force the app to stop by killing it in the system settings, my alarm will not repeat. Here is the code for setting the alarm:

```
AlarmManager am = (AlarmManager) context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
Intent i = new Intent("myapp.START_MONITORING");
PendingIntent pi = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis(), elapsedTime, pi);
```

To start my service I do the following:

```
Intent intent = new Intent(context, MyService.class);
ContextWrapper cw = (ContextWrapper) context;
cw.startService(intent);
```

Notice that context used for setting the alarm and starting the service are the same. They are located in the same method. The context is delivered to this method whenever the AlarmManager fires the alarm. If I kill the app while the service is running, theoretically, the service should start again at the next interval. But I have a suspicion that the AlarmManager keeps track of this context and if the service dies, it probably is killing the alarm as well.

Is there any way I can start my service with a context that is not the context passed in from the alarm? Maybe by doing that, I can prevent the alarm from getting killed.

Answer (score 2):

Alarms are killed if a user manually kills your service or app and they will not repeat again until the user starts the service or app manually (or the device reboots) - even if the alarm is set to repeat. Well that sucks. See:

[How to create a persistent AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103088/753632)

Answer (score 0):

After the completion of alarm service.,Use `am.cancel(pi)`