# Keep alive Service in background?

Tags: android, service, android-activity

For a demo I print a Toast after Evert 10 sec. using `Service` class.

It works fine, I'm getting the Toast after every 10 sec if I am on the Activity when I leave the app, Service is not giving the o/p.

**But I want to that toast either I'll kill the App or back press** Here is code snippet :

*ServiceDemo.java*

```
public class ServiceDemo extends Activity {

private Handler myHandler = new Handler();
private Runnable drawRunnable = new Runnable() {

    @Override
    public void run() {
        as();
        myHandler.postDelayed(this, 10000);
    }
};

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_service_demo);

    myHandler.postDelayed(drawRunnable, 10000);

    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

public void as(){
    startService(new Intent(this, MyService.class));
}

@Override
protected void onPause() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onPause();
}
}
```

*Service.java*

```
public class MyService extends Service {

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public void onCreate() {
    Toast.makeText(this, "HOHO Service Created...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {
}

@Override
public void onStart(Intent intent, int startid) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
}
```

**Edit 1**

```
 moveTaskToBack(true);
```

I put this into the onBackPressed method I Service give the o/p if I am not on the screen but When I kill the App, `Service not responding`

Comment: start a foregourn service . http://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html

Comment: I found it but could not understand . How to use it in this case @Raghunandan

Comment: Can you give me any example link or tutorial link for this @Raghunandan

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to override onStartCommand instead of onStart()

like:

```
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startid)
{
   Toast.makeText(this, "Service Started...", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    return Service.START_STICKY;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think `AlarmManager` is what you want.

Comment: I have using this and I have done with the full code and its running but ... now I want to do this thing only Service class .... And Tutorial said ... you can run your service in the background

Answer (score 0):

You have to user AlarmManager, here's an example : [Alarm Manager Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4459058/alarm-manager-example)

Your task will be executed even if the application is terminated.

But if the application is killed by the user, the Alarm will be canceled. See this discussion [How to create a persistent AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101818/how-to-create-a-persistent-alarmmanager)

Comment: I have using this and I have done with the full code and its running but ... now I want to do this thing only Service class .... And Tutorial said ... you can run your service in the background