# Schedule notification using alarm manager in xamarin forms for android

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android, local

- I have created a dependencie to show the notifications
- In My DeviceDetails_Droid.cs I've set set alarm for 30 seconds
- The functionality for local notification works perfectly when app is 
  active but when I killed the app (close app) the alarm    receiver
  not    getting called.

---

```
public void ShowNotification(string message, string title)
{

Intent alarmIntent = new Intent(Forms.Context, typeof(AlarmReceiver));
alarmIntent.PutExtra ("message", message);
alarmIntent.PutExtra ("title", title);

    PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Forms.Context, 0, alarmIntent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
    AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) Forms.Context.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);

    //TODO: For demo set after 5 seconds.
    alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, DateTime.Now.Millisecond + 30000, pendingIntent);
}
```

---

- In Androids MainActivity

---

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
{
    public override void OnReceive (Context context, Intent intent)
    {

        var message = intent.GetStringExtra ("message");
        var title = intent.GetStringExtra ("title");

        var notIntent = new Intent (context, typeof(MainActivity));
        var contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (context, 0, notIntent, PendingIntentFlags.CancelCurrent);
        var manager = NotificationManagerCompat.From (context);

        var style = new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle();
        style.BigText(message);



        //Generate a notification with just short text and small icon
        var builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder (context)
            .SetContentIntent (contentIntent)
            .SetSmallIcon (Resource.Drawable.Icon)
            .SetContentTitle (title)
            .SetContentText (message)
            .SetStyle (style)
            .SetWhen (Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis ())
            .SetAutoCancel (true);

        var notification = builder.Build();
        manager.Notify(0, notification);
    }
}
```

---

- And in manifest file

---

```
<receiver 
 android:name=".AlarmReceiver" 
 android:enabled="true" 
 android:exported="true" 
 android:process=":remote" 
 android:label="AlarmReceiver">
```

---

- The above code is running perfectly when app is in running state
     But the notification is not working when app is closed or killed

Comment: you need to implement Background Service to make it work after the app is killed or closed. Refer this : http://stackoverflow.com/a/34207954/6127411.

Comment: In Manifest <receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote" android:label="AlarmReceiver">

Answer (score 8):

1) If someone kills your app, alarms registered to your app are cancelled.

2) You can start your service in the background on `Boot` of the device in order to register your alarms, or run any other code you need to setup your notifications...

- Add "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" to your BroadcastReceiver:

---

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[]{"android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"}, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
public class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
```

---

- In your manifest add in the boot complete permission:

---

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK"/>
<uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"></uses-permission>
```

---

In the case of Xamarin's [Stock Price example](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/android/application_fundamentals/services/part_3_-_viewing_running_services_and_stock_service_example/), if you set "RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" you are "auto" restart your service and the your will start receiving notifications upon reboot of their phone without first launching your app:

```
[BroadcastReceiver]
[IntentFilter(new string[]{StockService.StocksUpdatedAction,Boo "android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED"}, Priority = (int)IntentFilterPriority.LowPriority)]
public class StockNotificationReceiver : BroadcastReceiver
```

3) **You can use a `Service` vs. a `SeviceIntent` and override the `StartCommandResult` to return `Sticky`**

With a Sticky-based Service, it is restarted if it gets terminated.

> Constant to return from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int): if this service's process is killed while it is started (after returning from onStartCommand(Intent, int, int)), then leave it in the started state but don't retain this delivered intent. Later the system will try to re-create the service. Because it is in the started state, it will guarantee to call onStartCommand(Intent, int, int) after creating the new service instance; if there are not any pending start commands to be delivered to the service, it will be called with a null intent object, so you must take care to check for this.

```
    public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
    {
        return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
    }
```

Comment: I looked at the first paragraph [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/provider/AlarmClock.html) and it sounds like maybe the `SET_ALARM` permission is not needed in this case, is that true? I am trying to schedule local notifications and wondering if I should be adding that permission or not. Seems to be working so far without it. Thanks.

Comment: @hvaughan3 if you are writing your own alarm clock application, you need to set that perm to receive intents. If you are receiving intents from an alarm  app, no it is not needed.

Comment: That makes sense now. Thank you

Comment: @SushiHangover, can you make us a favor and edit the question posted to your answer, because i want to know which class i am supposed to place the Dependency in PCL

Comment: @LutaayaHuzaifahIdris Are you talking about a `Xamarin.Forms`' based dependency service? If so post a new question as the question was concerning `Xamarin.Android` native and all this code is written within a Xamarin.Android application or library project

Comment: @SushiHangover, help me on this one please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47052256/how-can-i-call-a-broadcastreceiver-inside-a-service-with-a-local-notification-x

Comment: @SushiHangover, i would suggest also please to Edit your answer , and make a Tutorial Demonstrating A scheduled Alarm notification with sticky service , i will be very grateful

Comment: @SushiHangover, am having a problem with your answer the App crashes when i call **StartService()** in the MainActivity why ?, i dont know why. Check out this please https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47092507/android-crashes-with-startservice-calling?noredirect=1#

Answer (score 0):

AlarmManager will work when the App is running in Foreground or in Background. But when the App is quit/force-stopped/killed Alarm Manager is also killed. Alarm will go off again only if Android is Re-booted or App is again launched by the user. Check these answers also for reference [link1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19828231/3319076) , [link2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9103088/3319076)

Comment: Is this still the case?  The links you've shared are a bit dated now.

Comment: So how do existing  Alarm Apps do ?, because for them they still work however much they are killed