# Android crashes with StartService() calling

Tags: android, xamarin, service

I am trying to start a service so that I can receive scheduled notifications, but when the scheduled time reaches the **Application crashes** (Unfortunately the App has stopped), why is this happening.

> One of the challenges am facing, unfortunately, i don't know how to see the **Exception**
>   **of a service** in a Log.

**My Manifest is below:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.diabetics.Diabetes">
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="15" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="com.android.alarm.permission.SET_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REBOOT" />
    <application android:label="Diabetes">
        <!-- Will not be called unless the application explicitly enables it -->
        <service android:name="com.diabetics.Diabetes.AppStickyService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.diabetics.Diabetes.AppStickyService" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>
        <receiver android:name="com.diabetics.Diabetes.AlarmReceiver" android:enabled="false" android:exported="true" android:process=":remote" android:label="AlarmReceiver">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

**Then my Service class**

```
[Service(Exported = true, Name = "com.diabetics.Diabetes.AppStickyService")]
    public class AppStickyService : Service
    {

        public override void OnCreate()
        {
            base.OnCreate();
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Service started", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sticky Service - Created");
        }

        public override StartCommandResult OnStartCommand(Android.Content.Intent intent, StartCommandFlags flags, int startId)
        {

            return StartCommandResult.Sticky;
        }

        public override Android.OS.IBinder OnBind(Android.Content.Intent intent)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Sticky Service - Binded");
            Toast.MakeText(this, "Service started", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            return null;
        }

        public override void OnDestroy()
        {
            try
            {
                base.OnDestroy();
            }
            catch (Java.Lang.IllegalStateException ex)
            {
                //Log.Debug("MainActivity.OnDestroy", ex, "The activity was destroyed twice");
            }

            cancelnotification(0);

        }
}
```

***Then how am calling the `StartService()` in `MainApplication.cs`.***

```
[Application]
public class MainApplication : Application
{
    ISetAlarm alarmService;
    public static Context AppContext;

    public MainApplication()
    {

    }
    public MainApplication(IntPtr handle, JniHandleOwnership transer) : base(handle, transer)
    {
    }


    public override void OnCreate()
    {

        base.OnCreate();
        AppContext = this.ApplicationContext;

        try
        {

            StartService();
            alarmService = new SetAlarmImplementation();

            alarmService.SetAlarm(12, 14, "hello", "great work ");
        }

        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Error  " + e);

        }
    }



    public void SetAlarm(int hour, int minute, string title, string message)
    {

        AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)));
        Intent myintent = new Intent(Android.App.Application.Context, typeof(AppStickyService));
        myintent.PutExtra("message", message);
        myintent.PutExtra("title", title);
        //PendingIntent pendingintent = PendingIntent.GetBroadcast(Android.App.Application.Context, 0, myintent, PendingIntentFlags.UpdateCurrent);
        PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)), 0);

        Java.Util.Date date = new Java.Util.Date();
        Java.Util.Calendar cal = Java.Util.Calendar.Instance;
        cal.TimeInMillis = Java.Lang.JavaSystem.CurrentTimeMillis();
        cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.HourOfDay, hour);
        cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Minute, minute);
        cal.Set(Java.Util.CalendarField.Second, 0);
        AlarmManager alarmManager = Android.App.Application.Context.GetSystemService(Android.Content.Context.AlarmService) as AlarmManager;
        alarmManager.Set(AlarmType.RtcWakeup, cal.TimeInMillis, pintent);
        // alarmManager.Cancel(pintent);

    }





    public void StartService()
    {

        AppContext.StartService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)));
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {

            StartService(new Intent(this, typeof(AppStickyService)));


        }




    }

    public static void StopService()
    {
        AppContext.StopService(new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)));
        if (Android.OS.Build.VERSION.SdkInt >= Android.OS.BuildVersionCodes.Kitkat)
        {
            // Toast.MakeText(this,"Service started", ToastLength.Long).Show();

            //PendingIntent pintent = PendingIntent.GetService(AppContext, 0, new Intent(AppContext, typeof(AppStickyService)), 0);
            // AlarmManager alarm = (AlarmManager)AppContext.GetSystemService(Context.AlarmService);
            //alarm.Cancel(pintent);
        }
    }
```

> The Application Crashes, and I don't know the exact exception, how can
>   I perfect this, please.

**My UPDATED stack trace:**

```
  11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime: Process: com.diabetics.Diabetes, PID: 27931
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime: android.runtime.JavaProxyThrowable: System.InvalidOperationException: You MUST call Xamarin.Forms.Init(); prior to using it.
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:   at Xamarin.Forms.Device.get_PlatformServices () [0x00007] in <1982f4f36e0b4e118327ea411be26e7b>:0 
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:   at Xamarin.Forms.Device.GetAssemblies () [0x00000] in <1982f4f36e0b4e118327ea411be26e7b>:0 
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:   at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Initialize () [0x00008] in <1982f4f36e0b4e118327ea411be26e7b>:0 
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:   at Xamarin.Forms.DependencyService.Get[T] (Xamarin.Forms.DependencyFetchTarget fetchTarget) [0x00000] in <1982f4f36e0b4e118327ea411be26e7b>:0 
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:   at Diabetes.localDB.MedicationDatabase..ctor () [0x00008] in <1d32457e60b941eda588a8ccf582a78e>:0 
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:   at Diabetes.Droid.AlarmReceiver.OnReceive (Android.Content.Context context, Android.Content.Intent intent) [0x000e9] in <a946f75a1e344852a2da6cb15bcf50b1>:0 
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:   at Android.Content.BroadcastReceiver.n_OnReceive_Landroid_content_Context_Landroid_content_Intent_ (System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this, System.IntPtr native_context, System.IntPtr native_intent) [0x00017] in <d278c06ad5684d6882c743a94a93ebc2>:0 
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:   at (wrapper dynamic-method) System.Object:6ad989d4-d363-48db-abae-68048f2d711b (intptr,intptr,intptr,intptr)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at md5d7f88582010464bb2d25fa2f1bb63590.AlarmReceiver.n_onReceive(Native Method)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at md5d7f88582010464bb2d25fa2f1bb63590.AlarmReceiver.onReceive(AlarmReceiver.java:29)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2910)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:175)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1565)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:111)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:207)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5728)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:789)
11-03 18:45:03.314 27931 27931 E AndroidRuntime:    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:679)
```

Comment: can you please add log here?

Comment: Don't filter the logcat. Use the option "No Filters" and you will see the logs.

Comment: @SamirBhatt, read well my post

Comment: @MuratK., you know i see the service started after killing the App , and when i kill it the IDE stops reading log from the phone , so eventually i see the service strating by the help of the Toast , but when the time schedulled reaches it crashes

Comment: @MuratK., what do you mean by not filtering ?

Comment: please put the logcat

Comment: @Ajeetyadav, i already stated this in my post that i cant read a log of a service

Comment: I have failed to read it because ,when the application is running the Notification comes , but when i kill it , the service starts and when the schedulled time reaches the notification doesnt comes , but it just crashes

Comment: @IdrisStack; If you do not see a stacktrace in the IDE, you might want to start a terminal and use `adb logcat -v threadtime` to see all that is logged by the device or you could try to `adb pull /data/system/dropbox` to see if anything was dumped by dropbox. Not having a stracktrace is not useful here

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE, i run `adb logcat -v threadtime` in the terminal but am getting this  `-bash: adb: command not found`, should i need to target the project by changing a directory

Comment: @IdrisStack You should go to the directory where your Android SDK is located and run it from there. It is located in the `platform-tools` directory of the SDK

Comment: Am using visual studio

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE, i have updated my post

Comment: @0xDEADC0DE,  what does this mean `11-03 16:40:26.160   819  1476 D AlarmManager:  whichBatch = -1
11-03 16:40:26.160   819  1476 D AlarmManager: rebatchAllAlarmsLocked  batch.size() = 1
11-03 16:40:26.160   819  1476 D AlarmManager:  whichBatch = -1
11-03 16:40:26.161   819  1476 D AlarmManager: rebatchAllAlarmsLocked  batch.size() = 1
11-03 16:40:26.162   819  1476 D AlarmManager:  whichBatch = -1
11-03 16:40:26.162   819  1476 D AlarmManager: rebatchAllAlarmsLocked  batch.size() = 1`

Comment: @IdrisStack Which `StartService(....)` is being called? Both? You need to debug your code, set a breakpoint and step line-by-line.

Comment: @SushiHangover, it's  AppStickyService, check in my post it's a service ,  i have placed a breakpoint , but the error occurs after i kill the Application , so i don't i think if the break point will manage it. Because my concept of the Application is to build a clock alarm App , so i used Service as you sais in one of your posts to make the Alarm sticky , even when the App is not launched the Alarm should be abale to fire

Comment: @SushiHangover, this is what i get when i put a break point `Diabetes.Droid.MainApplication.OnCreate() in /Users/haleem/Projects/Diabetes/Droid/MainApplication.cs:44
Android.App.Application.n_OnCreate(System.IntPtr jnienv, System.IntPtr native__this) in 
object.b661b412-676f-43a3-828a-e8e0a7a3ad37( arg0,  arg1) in`

Comment: I have updated my post @SushiHangover

Comment: or please at @SushiHangover, if you have an example of an alarm clock in xamarin android which has a broadcast + a sticky service please help me with it.

Comment: I have for sure searched for an alarm clock implementation xamarin , but i have found none.